# Sequelize.js' association are not rendered on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have two models.

```
var self = {
    User: sequelize.define('user', {
        id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER,primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true},
        name: {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false}
    }),

    Role: sequelize.define('role', {
        id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER,primaryKey: true,autoIncrement: true},      
        name: {type: Sequelize.STRING,allowNull: false} 
   })
}
```

I have also specify association between them.

```
self.User.belongsTo(self.Role);
```

Part of controller user.js:

```
list: function(req, res){
   models.User.findAll({offset: offset, limit: limit}).success(function (users) {
            if (req.params.format == 'html') {
                res.render('admin/user/list.html', {
                    title: 'Users',
                    layout: layout,
                    users: users
                });
            }   else if (req.params.format == 'json') {
                res.json(users);
            }
   }
```

In view list.html:

```
<% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= user.id %></td>
        <td><a href="/admin/user/<%= user.id %>/show.html"><%= user.name %></a></td>
        <td><%= user.getRole().name %></td>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

If we call /list.html We obtained undefined role on page for each user.

And if we call /list.json we obtain:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"user1", "role_id":1},
[{"id":2,"name":"user2", "role_id":1},
[{"id":3,"name":"user3", "role_id":2},
...
```

How do I get the role for each user in list.html and in json response?
Or maybe there is some better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for not getting the associated role is the fact, that getting the role of that user is handled asynchronously. This means 1.) that you need to use `user.getRole().success(function(role){})` and 2.) that you need to read the role in the controller because EJS isn't capable of handling asynchronicity. Hope that helps :)

Comment: So, to create a list of 20 users with its role, do we must do 20 of additional requests for getting the associated role? But in pure sql we can do this in one query.

Comment: right now it's exactly like this. You could also try to utilize the sequelize.query method, which executes sql queries and returns stuff as object. This however is more a hack then anything else. This is how it could work: `sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM users, roles WHERE users.id = roles.user_id", null, {raw: true})`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
models.User.findAll({offset: offset, limit: limit, include: [models.Role]})
```

see http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-eager-loading for more details